# VariationalBound with and interpolated trial function

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation, variational-calculus

I am trying to solve a Sturm-Liouville problem using the VariationalBound function of Mathematica, as recomended in the [wolfram mathworld site](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sturm-LiouvilleEquation.html). The example given in the Mathematica documentation is this:

```
In[2]:= eqn = y''''[x] + Pi y''[x] + 5  y'[x] == \[Lambda] y[x]; 

In[3]:= sol = 
 VariationalBound[{y[x] eqn[[1]], y[x]^2}, y[x], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
  E^(c x), {c}]

Out[3]= {-1.74565, {c -> -0.633739}}
```

It is important to observe that if the trial function (Exp^(cx)) is far from the solution to the diferential equation, the compiler will show some error. For example, chosing cx as a trial function gives the following error messages:

```
In[227]:= sol = 
 VariationalBound[{ y[x] eqn[[1]], y[x]^2}, 
  y[x], {x, 0, Infinity}, (c x), {c}]

During evaluation of In[227]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.

During evaluation of In[227]:= Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.

During evaluation of In[227]:= VariationalBound::nonex: No meaningful extremum found in the specified parameter interval(s).

During evaluation of In[227]:= Part::partw: Part {1,1,1,2} of {{}} does not exist.

 Out[227]= {0., {{}}[[{1, 1, 1, 2}]]}
```

In more complicated differential equations could be necessary to use a trial function that is an Interpolating Function of some data or an approximated solution to the ODE. So I tried this as an exercise:

```
tab = Table[E^(0.01 i), {i, 0, 100000}];

Ifun = Interpolation[tab, InterpolationOrder -> 4, Method -> "Spline"];


In[230]:= sol = 
 VariationalBound[{ y[x] eqn[[1]], y[x]^2}, y[x], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
  Ifun[c x], {c}]

During evaluation of In[230]:= VariationalBound::int: The integral(s) involved cannot be evaluated.

During evaluation of In[230]:= VariationalBound::int: The integral(s) involved cannot be evaluated.
```

Changing the position of the parameter c do not make things better. So it seems that an interpolating function can not be used as trial function, but I think it must. Any help?

Comment: Your approach has many problems.  `tab` contains numbers as large as `Exp[10^4]`, which is extraordinarily large, apparently too large for `Interpolation` to handle with splines.  Since `Ifun, if it could be constructed, would be defined only for `x` between 0 and 10^4, `Ifun[c x]` with `c` negative` would be undefined.  Finally, numerical integrals cannot be performed over an infinite range.  Nonetheless, an interesting problem.  One thing you might try is defining `Ifun` for negative arguments only.

Comment: @bbgodfrey You are right the integral is not performed over all the real axis, this is a problem.  I wonder if adding some Lagrange multiplier with a boundary condition could solve the finitude problem, however I failed to get a solution in this case as well.